# Abstract classes or partial?

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class

I have a number of tasks which can be carried out by similar (yet slightly different) classes which all share a common set of functionality.

My intention is to extract this functionality into a parent class, and because I don't want this to be implemented itself I've marked it `abstract`.

However all of the calling classes call a single method - which used to contain the extracted common functionality.  I don't want to `override` the parent class method but I want it to be executed *in addition* to what is defined in the child class.

I initially thought this was a job for a partial method, but I think this will break semantics somewhat.  So what is the best way forward for me? Experiencing a bit of tunnel vision here.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify this a bit " I don't want to ovveride the parent class method but I want it to be executed in addition to what is defined in the child class."?  Where is your functionality defined in the child class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public void TheSingleMethod()
    {
        CommonFunctionality();

        InternalDo();
    }

    protected abstract void InternalDo();

    private void CommonFunctionality()
    {
        // Common functionality goes here.
    }
}

public class Derived : Parent
{
    protected override void InternalDo()
    {
        // Additional code of child goes here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just call base.InternalDo() in the overridden method?

Comment: The reason is that you can't enforce it. If you want to *enforce* that the common functionality is executed for ALL derived classes, the way I showed is the way to go. If it is *optional*, your suggestion would be the way to go.

Comment: This looks like the template pattern to me, would I be correct?

Comment: @m.edmondson: Yes, a very simple template, but it is the template method pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a [Template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

For example

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    public void Common Method() {
        // Common tasks

        // Call template method
        this.SubclassSpecificMethod();

        // Can also do more code after the call to the template method
    }

    protected abstract void SubclassSpecificMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like composition and the [Decorator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) could be another option for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do:

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void Method() {
        // Common tasks
    }
}

class RealClass : BaseClass 
{
    public void Method() {
         base.Method();
         // custom tasks for this class
    }
}
```

Comment: This method wouldn't enforce that the common functionality is executed for all children. See [the comment on my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615909/abstract-classes-or-partial/9615974#comment12201179_9615974) for a little bit more info.

Comment: I know, but author didn't requested that. My method gives more flexibility. Depending on needs of author, one or other is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, he requested it: "I don't want to override the parent class method but I want it to be executed in addition to what is defined in the child class"